# Length of a C string: std::strlen() vs. std::char_traits<char>::length()

Tags: c++

Both are equivalent in that they return the length of the null-terminated character sequence. Are there reasons of preferring one to the other?

Comment: The second version uses the Standard C++ header `<string>` while the first uses the C header `<cstring>`.

Comment: I always prefer to avoid (of course great) C functions if there's a C++ alternative.

Comment: @MM. (provided that you are programming in C++, of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Zack Howland and Konrad Rudolph have a point. Thanks. I accept both answers. The summarized reply would be:
There doesn't seem to be any except personal preference either for shorter code or the C++ standard library (I leave out generalization since it wasn't the point of the question as can be seen from the title).

Answer (score 6):

Use the simpler alternative. `std::char_traits::length` is great and all, but for C strings it does **the same** and is much longer code.

Do yourself a favour and avoid code bloat. I’m a huge fan of C++ functions over C equivalent (e.g. I will **never** use `std::strcpy` or `std::memcpy`, there’s a perfectly fine `std::copy`). But avoiding `std::strlen` is just silly.

One reason to use C++ functions exclusively is interface uniformity: for instance, both `std::strcpy` and `std::memcpy` have atrocious interfaces. However, `std::strlen` is a perfectly fine algorithm in the best tradition of C++. It doesn’t generalise, true, but the neither do other class-specific free functions found in the standard library.

Comment: Well, not completely silly (if you cannot be assured that there is a null terminator in the string), but you can address that with `strnlen`.  The char_traits version is more useful if you must support varying sized byte sets (e.g. a build for UNICODE and a build for non-UNICODE).

Comment: @Zac Well, (obviously) I was talking about the direct comparison between the aforementioned alternatives.

Comment: Hit add too fast ... hadn't finished my thought and you already replied :)

Answer (score 3):

`std::strlen()` is a holdover from the C Standard Library and only operates on a `const char*` (it is unsafe in that it has undefined behavior if the string is not null terminated).  If the string is using a wide character set (e.g. `const unsigned short*`), `std::strlen()` is useless.

`std::char_traits<T>::length()` will operate on whatever the `T` type is (e.g. if it is an `unsigned short`, it will still operate properly, but also requires a null terminated value - that is the last value must be `T(0)` - if an array of `T`'s passed to it is not null terminated, behavior is undefined as well).

In general, when dealing with strings, it is better to use `std::string::length()` instead of using C-style character strings.

Comment: If a not null-terminated character sequence is passed to `char_traits::length()`, it's undefined behaviour too.

Comment: @Ruup True.  I left that out as I thought it was self explanatory, but I'll add it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17, `std::char_traits<char>::length()` is `constexpr` meaning it should be computed at compilation time if possible (i.e. if the parameter is constant).

In practice, modern compiler already optimize `strlen` to compute string length at compilation too for `constexpr` expressions, even though it's not really standard.

That being said, I agree `strlen` is more readable.

Answer (score -2):

`std::strlen()` is a C standard library compatibility (even though it is part of ISO C++) function that takes `const char*` as an argument. `length()` is a method of the `std::string` family of classes. So if you want to use `strlen()` on `std::string` you'd have to write:

```
strlen(mystring.c_str())
```

which is less tidy than `mystr.length()`. Apart from that, there should be no tangible difference (for `char` type, that is).

Comment: `std::char_traits<T>::length(const T* t)` is not part of `std::string`.  It is part of `std::char_traits`.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said a "family" of classes comprising std::string.

Comment: That wording is probably not what you wanted to convey, then.  `std::string` uses `std::char_traits` (as do other STD classes like iostreams), but `std::char_traits` knows nothing of `std::string`.  In fact, `std::string::length` does not even look for a null terminator (it returns the value of the `size` member).  `std::char_traits<T>::length()` does look for a null terminator.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood OP. Apart from that, there *is* a tangible difference between `std::strlen` and `std::basic_string::length`. The former assumes null-terminated strings, the latter allows null-chars *inside* the string.

Comment: You should always afraid of using `strlen` over `string::c_str()` which sometimes reports false length due to `\0` within strings.

Comment: Thanks. That I didn't know.